# ListView item stays highlighted once scrolled

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I have a listview in my app, if I click one item from the list, it gets highlighted. Then if I click another item, that highlight shifts to that item. But if the scroll the list after selecting an item and then select another item from another part of the list, both of them remains highlighted. But not if I don't scroll the screen. What is causing this? And how to deal with it?

ListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.mp3;



import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> list;

    public  ListAdapter(Context _context,List<String> list)
    {
        this._context=_context;
        this.list=list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
     @Override

        public int getViewTypeCount() {

         return getCount();
        }

        @Override

        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

         return position;
        }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           View row = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, viewGroup, false);
            }


            TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
            textView.setText(list.get(position).toString());



        return row;
    }



}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mp3;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCompletionListener {

    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
    ArrayList<String> listTest;
     ArrayList<String> listSoundNames;
    ImageButton play,stop,back,next;
    String songpath,song,title;
    int index,current_position;
    File[] listFile;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    MediaPlayer mp,mp2;
    ActionBar bar;
    private Boolean state=false;
    private static int save = -1;
    int count=0;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context _context = this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        song = sharedPref.getString("songname", "name");

        mp=new MediaPlayer();
        mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);


        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        //list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); 

        _context=this;





        listTest = new ArrayList<String>( );
        listSoundNames=new ArrayList<String>();

        play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
        back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev);
        next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

        //adding listeners
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);


        //action bar controls
        bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DF0174")));
        //bar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 

        EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        getActionBar().setCustomView(editText);


        //bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        //bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Scanner("/sdcard/");///storage path


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////*Adding listener to songs*//////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(listTest.size() != 0)
        {
            //listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,R.layout.simplerow, listSoundNames);

            ListAdapter listAdapter=new ListAdapter(_context,listSoundNames);
            list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                ///////////////////changing list item background on click///////////////////

                list.clearChoices();
                //list.setSelection(position);
                view.setSelected(true);  ///////////////////PROBLEM/////////////

                for(int a = 0; a < parent.getChildCount(); a++)
                {

                    parent.getChildAt(a).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


                }


                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //accessing song path
                String selected = listTest.get(position);
                list.setItemChecked(position, true);//

                //accessing the song name
                String name = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                title = name;
                //bar.setTitle(title);
                //Log.e(TAG, name);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try{
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.setDataSource(listTest.get(position));//source
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                    index = position;
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    }
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}



            }


            });




            }

        }



        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////*Songs added here to list*////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void Scanner(String path) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            {
                try 
                {
                        File fl = new File(path);
                        File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();              

                        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
                         {
                            String s = listOfFile.getName();

                            if(s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                            {

                            songpath = listOfFile.getPath();
                            listTest.add(songpath);//adding song names to list
                            //listTest.toString().replaceFirst(songpath, s);



                            // store file name in listSoundNames
                            int pos = s.lastIndexOf(".");
                            if (pos > 0)
                            {
                                song = s.substring(0, pos);
                            }
                            listSoundNames.add(song);

                            }


                            /////////////////////////////////
                            File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                            if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                            Scanner(path+s+"/");
                            }
                            ////////////////////////////////


                        }



                }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            }

            }








    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.equals(play))
        {
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.pause();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //change in button image//
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
            else
            {
                mp.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //change in button image//
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                //
            }
        }


            if (v.equals(back))
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                //bar.setTitle(song);
                if(index!=0)
                {
                index = index -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    index = (list.getAdapter().getCount()-1)-1;

                }

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(listTest.get(index).toString());//getting the path of next song
                try {


                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);//setting new data source 


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();///PROBLEM:MOVING HERE AFTER CLICKING NEXT BUTTON
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }        
                mp.start();//PROBLEM: NOT PLAYING
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            if (v.equals(next))
            {

                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                index = index +1;


                Uri uri = Uri.parse(listTest.get(index).toString());//getting the path of next song

                try {


                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);//setting new data source 


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();///PROBLEM:MOVING HERE AFTER CLICKING NEXT BUTTON
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }        
                mp.start();//PROBLEM: NOT PLAYING
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mp.stop();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }*/

    //////////////////////////////////////////Search box/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);



         SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);   
                searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml(("<font color = #ffffff>"+"Listen Now"+"</font>")));



            SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
                {
                    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type"+newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
                {
                    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try 
                    {
                            File fl = new File("/sdcard/");
                            File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();  
                            String selectedPath="";

                            for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
                             {
                                String s = listOfFile.getName();

                                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(query) && s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                                {

                                    selectedPath= listOfFile.getPath();//not receiving the path:PROBLEM:HOLDING THE POSITION FOR LIST ITEM


                                //listTest.add(songpath);//adding song names to list
                                //listTest.toString().replaceFirst(songpath, s);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listOfFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                /*mp.setDataSource(selectedPath);
                                mp.prepare();
                                mp.start();*/

                                }



                                /////////////////////////////////
                                File f = new File("/sdcard/"+s+"/");
                                if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                                Scanner("/sdcard/"+s+"/");
                                }
                                ////////////////////////////////


                            }



                    }

                catch (Exception e) { }

                    return true;
                }
            };
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);



            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem is the way Android recycles the ListView items. A way to prevent something like this is to manually save wich item is clicked. In your adapter you can make a variable wich holds the current selected item. In your `getView` you will have to check if the current item is the same as selected. It will look something like this:

`if(row==currentSelected){
   //set background color
 else{
    //another background color -> this is important otherwise all listview items will have the same background color after swiping up and down
 }`

Comment: How to get that value in adapter class? Sorry if I sound stupid, I am new with viewholder so not a master in these yet..

Comment: @Sri if I understand you correctly you want to have the currentSelected in another class. If that is the case you can make a getter for the variable like: `public View getCurrentView(){ return currentView} `. If I understood you wrong please let me know

Comment: I mean you said that I should create a variable in list adapter class to hold the value of the current selected item, but I have implemented the onclick in mainactivity, so how to get that value in list adapter

Comment: Then its just the other way around. Create a getter in the class where you defined the onclick. Make sure you pass that class to the adapter in the constructor so you can reach it.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, try with this.
>
> 1- Your activity extend from ListActivity. 2-Create the next adapater
>   for your list, you can create this adapter inside your activity:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return items[position].hashCode();
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item,             

container, false);
    }

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1))
                .setText(getItem(position));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)                                                                                 a     convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Icon);
   imageView.setImageResource(imagesId[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

> items = Array String with the text items. imagesId = Array with the
>   image's id in your draweable.
>
> In the layout create the next list_item.xml

```
<com.Test.CheckableLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_Icon"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="IconDescription"
        android:layout_width="60dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/hideable_text_color" />


    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_hideable_item"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />

</com.Test.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

> In your Activity set adapter in the ListView:

```
 ListView listTest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTest);
        listTest .setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
```

> If you need a best example, go to Import Sample -> Select your version
>   y go to List, here is excelente example for the list multi select.

Comment: Why are you using array?

Comment: You can use other types of lists , while you let yourself get the position .